# Hosiped.com is not live yet Google cloud virtual machine instance shows running

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I have a Wordpress site hosiped.com that was live but is down at the moment. Am using Google cloud hosting.

The virtual machine instance shows running but I can't troubleshoot what the problem is. Who can help?

I wanted the site to be live.

Answer (score 0):

You can check first the [serial logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/viewing-serial-port-output#cloud-logging) of your VM Instance.

The instance's operating system, BIOS, and other system-level entities often write output to the serial ports which is helpful in troubleshooting your instance.